# Find out the number of Days and nights using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to find out the number of days and nights in a given date range in sql. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: between any date range there will alwayas same number of days and nights will be there.Are you looking for time specific?

Comment: Define day and night. From x to y hours?

Comment: in case if one person checkin to a hotel at 12pm and check out in 12 am then number of nights is 1 and day is 0 like that i have a check date time and checkout datetime i tried datediff but got only the number of days

Comment: So you have two datetime columns to store check-in and check-out right? If check-in time is Jan 01 2012 9:00 PM and check-out is at Jan 01 2012 10:00 PM, do we need to consider this as one night?; if check-out is at Jan 02 2012 01:00 AM, do we need to count 1 day and 1 night?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
declare @t table(datefrom datetime, dateto datetime)
insert @t values('2012-01-01 11:30', '2012-01-01 12:30')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 11:30', '2012-01-02 00:30')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 12:30', '2012-01-02 13:00')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 12:30', '2012-01-02 00:30')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 00:00', '2012-01-03 00:00')

select datefrom, dateto,
datediff(day, datefrom - .5,dateadd(minute, -1, dateto)) nights,
datediff(day, datefrom, dateadd(minute, -1, dateto)+.5) days
from @t t
```

Result:

```
datefrom         dateto            nights days
2012-01-01 11:30 2012-01-01 12:30  1      1
2012-01-01 11:30 2012-01-02 00:30  2      1
2012-01-01 12:30 2012-01-02 13:00  1      2
2012-01-01 12:30 2012-01-02 00:30  1      1
2012-01-01 00:00 2012-01-03 00:00  2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Datediff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Nights

```
select DATEDIFF (d, getdate()-1,getdate())
```

Days

```
select DATEDIFF (d, getdate()-1,getdate()) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

See the AnandPhadke's comment, and here is the code :)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2012-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2012-02-01' 
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS [Days],  DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS [Nights ]
```